# Basic mysql regexp on an array of integers

Tags: mysql

I have a varchar field that holds an array of integers.

For example:

```
Row1: [2]
Row2: [1,8,346]
Row3: [10,54,245]
Row4: [4,25,3,7,46,14]
```

I need to be able to get all rows that have an instance of the selected id.
Kinda like if I could use the reverse of the IN function ...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN (4)
```

Although reversing the input/output of the IN function ...

To try and clarify:
Using the above number sets as rows.
I need to be able to get all rows that have ID 1 in the varchar group of numbers.
What I was trying looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '(1)';
```

When I perform the query for ID 1, the resultset should only have row 2, not row 3 (with 10 in the set)

Suggestions ?
TIA

Comment: So given an ID 4, you want all rows where the varchar field has 4 in it? Or given a varchar field (say `[1,10]`), you want all rows where the ID is 1 or 10? Which one? What is your desired output in your example "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN (4)"?

Comment: If an ID is 1, rows containing 10 (but not 1) should NOT be selected. Am I answering your question correctly ?

Comment: @user2977468 that's not what I meant, though I see I wrote it confusingly. But I understand what you mean now from your updated question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]';
```

The `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match word *boundaries*, meaning it won't match the 1 in '21' or the 1 in '10', but it *will* match the whole word 1.

See the very  bottom of [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/regexp.html) from the MySQL docs where they explain `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.